# how to show boxplot in jupyter?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, jupyter, boxplot

I have problem with showing below plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])`enter code here`
```

The error is:  module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'set_theme'
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, then I read the release note of v0.11.0 (September 2020) https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html

**Theming**

API The set() function has been renamed to set_theme() for more clarity about what it does. For the foreseeable future, set() will remain as an alias, but it is recommended to update your code.

So I uninstall and reinstall the seaborn, now it works :)

```
pip uninstall seaborn
pip install seaborn
```